# Searching the initial letter of a word using searchBar

Tags: iphone, ios, search, uisearchbar

In my app, i have a search bar in my contact list page tableview. now my code searches the list based on any letter even if the search text is at the middle of the firstname or lastname. But i want it to search only from the beginning. For example., the word "sh" should pull only "Shiva", "Sheela", etc., but not "sathish", "suresh" etc., can anyone help me on this?

and my code is

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
//---if there is something to search for---
if ([searchText length] > 0)
{
    isSearchOn = YES;
    canSelectRow = YES;
    self.ContactTableview.scrollEnabled = YES;
    searchTextValue = searchText;
    [searchResult removeAllObjects];

    for (NSString *str in ContactArray)
    {
        NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            if(range.length > 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the names.
            {
                [searchResult addObject:str];
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    //---nothing to search---
    isSearchOn = NO;
    canSelectRow = NO;
    self.ContactTableview.scrollEnabled = YES;
    //SearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    [TitleBarLabel setText:@"All Contacts"];

}
[ContactTableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: you can use `if([str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == 0)` NSNotFound means not found (obvious not?) and 0 means at the beginig

Comment: Thankyou for ur response frnd.. but in that case, how can i check both the starting letters of firstname and lastname?

Comment: I think you have to separate your contact name in 2 strings (first name and last name) then you make a if with 2 conditions using || (means OR), each of your condition is "Is my search text at the beginning of the substring"

Comment: could u pls let me know the if condition to find a string at the beginning of substring?

Comment: well, in my first comment is the code to test if a string is at the beginning of another one...

Answer (score 2):

try with predicates,in below code replace your values.

```
 NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@",@"A"];
    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AhfjA ", @"test1", @"Test", @"AntA", nil];
    NSArray *b = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
    NSLog(@"--%@",b);
```

O/P:-

```
(
    AntA,
    AntA
)
```